# Plasterboard on roof rafters. Is this okay?

Tags: drywall, attic

I am looking to convert the eaves of my loft into storage space. I plan to lay chipboard floor panels over the joists below, but not sure how to best cover the exposed sloping rafters above. I was thinking I could just screw plasterboard across the rafters and screw them on with plasterboard screws. Would there be any issues in doing this? I don’t plan to put any insulation between the rafters.

Thanks.

Comment: Not covering them at all is pretty standard in uninsulated attic storage.

Comment: Okay but it’s pretty dusty up there and want to make it nicer for storing stuff in the eves.

Comment: Is there insulation between the ceiling joists? (I understand you’re not going to add insulation between the roof joists.)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with installing drywall on the rafters. You mentioned it's pretty dusty up there, keep in mind the that dust is coming from the soffit vents and will continue to do so after the drywall is installed. You don't want to block off the soffit vents. Not sure where you live but if it's in a hot climate, do yourself a favor and wait until October to do the work. Good luck.